# Can I Create Folder Directory from browser in client machine using .net

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, directory, kendo-ui, local

Can we create a folder/directory in the client machine from the browser using.net?

I want to save a text file in the client directory, is it possible?

Comment: Shouldn't be possible. The browser is a sandbox and access to the machine is(and should be) restricted. Just give the user a download facility on your page and the browser will handle the rest like showing a "save to" dialog.

Comment: Ralf is right, it is not possible. It was in the distant past with the likes of plugins and activeX but no longer. You have no access to the client filesystem from the browser other than upload, download and reading and writing cookies.